# Which matrices generator $SO(p,q)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, quadratic-forms, orthogonal-matrices

I know that $SO(2)$ is generated by the set of matrices of the form

\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}

which can be used to find the matrices generated from various embeddings of $SO(2) \to SO(n)$. Is there a similar description for the matrix groups $SO(p,q)$?

Comment: These all have determinant $1$; they generate $SO(2)$ not $O(2)$. Indeed they comprise all elements of $SO(2)$.

Comment: You're right, thanks.